# How to deal with giant sparse matrices?

Tags: algorithms, matrix, recommender-system, large-data

I'm looking to do some heavy-duty manipulation of some really large and often very sparse matrices and I'm looking for the right tool for the job. These matrices will be much, much larger than the RAM of any single machine and will therefore likely be spread to several different machines.

I will want to perform all of the common matrix operations: multiplication, transpose, inverse, pseudo-inverse, SVD, Eigenvalue Decomposition, etc. Probably key among my concerns is that since the matrices will very likely be spread among several machines, I will want to minimize information sharing, because network latency is probably my biggest enemy.

I'm concerned that map-reduce (a la Hadoop) is not the right option because its focus is upon streaming large amounts of data between machines. [This book provides a great intro to map-reduce from an algorithmic perspective.](http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf) 
And lots of matrix operations are akin to giant JOIN operations which are known to be slow in map-reduce.

So... where should I go?

Comment: I don't know about multiple sources but there are some really good sparse linear algebra libraries out there. SuiteSparse (CHOLMOD, UMFPACK, etc.) are probably a good place to start looking. Mind you some of those CHOLMOD for example are available in the `Matrix` R-package. I don't know if those algorithms have multinode variants. Care to elaborate a bit more on your "*much, much larger than the RAM" claim*? Are you sure online algorithms are out of the question?

Comment: On another note, you mention a book at some point but you don't really say the name of it... (or link it).

Comment: @user11852 I fixed the link. As far as the much,much RAM thing... I'm extrapolating :-P I just finished a post on building semantic search using solr and numpy http://bit.ly/17oGX4w (I'm basically using collaborative filtering). On my simple toy set, this didn't get close to filling up RAM: 18K documents with 30K terms scattered through the index. A reasonably realistic set might have millions of documents and millions of terms. I'm also doing recommendations in this manner. So millions of users millions of products... same deal.

Comment: That sounds quite sparse to be honest, but then again millions of users tend to get big quite unexpectedly... Assuming you have $10^8$ users and each one has approximately 25 entries you need roughly 15Gigs of space for that matrix which is not the *end of the world*. Check Hama ( https://hama.apache.org/ ) I think it is quite related with what you want. (And I think that SO would probably offer you better answers)

Comment: You should perhaps scale down your ambitions a bit. You can handle e.g. eigenvalues with Lanczos' algorithm. I've used it with sparse matrices of size NxN with N in the billions, but if you intend to invert such a beast, there is no guarantee the inverse will be sparse, and then you're out of luck, even with a very big computer farm. So you should look carefully at exactly what kind of problems you need to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How large is large? I am working with 300k x 2k matrices on a single 30G box (see online options) with plenty left over. The key is to use things that work with sparse matrices. R has many good packages for that. You can also often break the problem into smaller pieces that can be solved separately then joined back.

If you want to go bigger, I would suggest http://spark.incubator.apache.org/ which has been developed to solve the problem of iterative algorithms (like alternating least squares). Redistribution is expensive in Hadoop due to network costs, so such algorithms suffer.

If you do end up trying it, please share your experience.